# Barra model: why standardize the fundamental risk factors?

Tags: risk, statistics, risk-management, factor-models, risk-models

The two main types of risk factors included in the famous Barra model are called the "fundamental factors", and "industry factors," and the thing that I do not understand is why are only the former standardized in the factor model?

On pg. 28 of Carol Alexander's very readable *[Practical Financial Econometrics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470998016)*, it says

[image]

What implicit market assumptions are being upheld by standardizing the risk factors like this? My two main questions are:

1. I previously thought regression variables were only standardized for the algorithm's sake, and not out of economic justifications. Indeed, *[this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29781/when-conducting-multiple-regression-when-should-you-center-your-predictor-varia)* suggests that all the risk factors in the model should be standardized.
2. What if the factors *are not* standardized, as this [link](https://faculty.washington.edu/ezivot/research/factormodellecture_handout.pdf) (on pg. 26) implies that they sometimes are?

I have not been able to find any sources on this matter, and would greatly appreciate someone explaining the rationale behind standardizing.

Answer (score 2):

Hi:  If you don't standardize, then each coefficient will have a different meaning. For example, suppose you have a company, ZZZ, that has a 1.5 standard deviation value of  "growth" factor exposure and a 2.5 standard deviation value of "liquidity" factor exposure. Then, if the model coefficient for growth is $\beta_{growth}$ and the model coefficient for liquidity is $\beta_{liquidity}$, then the  return ( I forget if it's the company's return or it's excess return )  attribution due to ZZZ's growth factor exposure is $1.5 \times \beta_{growth}$ and the return attribution due to its liquidity factor exposure is $2.5 \times \beta_{liquid}$.